# Remove Horizontal Scroll on Web Page

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I am getting a horizontal scroll bar which I need to remove. It appears that the footer is extending beyond the viewing capacity. I am trying to figure out a solution to remove the horizontal scroll bar. I have gone through similar cases posted on StackOverflow but they only give a temporary solution by using `overflow`.I have attached a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajivsr2309/a1e03cxd/1/)

CSS

```
/*Main Header Container */
.header{
  color:#FFFFFF;    /*White Color*/
  height:60px;
  width:100%;
  margin:auto;
}
/*Inner Logo Container on the left*/
.header_logo{
  width:40%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
}
#logo{
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:50%;
}
/*Inner Title Container on the right*/
.header_title{
  width:60%;
  float:left;
}
#titles{
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif,Georgia;
  font-size:97%;
  color:#B8B8B8;
}
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
}
li{
  display:inline-block;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:inherit;
  padding: 21px 10px;
}

ul a:hover{
  background-color:#666699;  /*Purple Color */

}

ul li ul{
  display:none; /*Hiding The Child Elements*/
}
li ul li{
    padding: 21px 10px;
    background-color:#666699 ;
    }


ul li:hover ul{   /*For all the ul elements whose parent is being hovered over*/
  display: block;
  position: absolute;

  width: 100%;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li ul li:hover{
    background-color:#C0C0C0;   
    }

  *{border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
/*Main Content Section*/
.content{
    height:525px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
    }
    img{
        width:100%;
        height:515px;
        }

    .footer {
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#707070;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer_upperspace  {
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
    height:40%;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer a:hover {
    background: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#footer_titles{
    position:relative;
    color:white;
    top:25%;
    left:3.5%;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif,Georgia;
    font-size:80%;
}

.footer_lowerspace{
    background-color:#707070;
    position: relative;
    top:20%;
    left:8%;
    width:100%;
}

#icon{
    width:2%;
    height:2%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="header">
   <div class="header_logo">
      <img id ="logo" src="images/civic-logo.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="header_title">
      <div id="titles">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT CIVIC</a>
            <li>
            <li>
               <a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>  
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">CEMENT</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">STEEL</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">BRICKS</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">SAND</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a> </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
   <img src="images/clt3.jpg">
</div>
<div class="footer">
<div class="footer_upperspace">
   <div id="footer_titles">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CIVIC HOME</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">INQUIRY</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="footer_lowerspace">
   <img id="icon" src="images/facebook.png" onClick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/')";>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try `overflow-x:hidden` specifically?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a1e03cxd/4/

Comment: There's still room for improvement but I think i addressed the biggest issues regarding your question in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fh909r9x/1/

First of all, you're missing a closing div tag on `.footer`.

You have the following styles on `.footer_lowerspace`:

```
left:8%;
width:100%;
```

This sets the footer 8% to the left based on it's parent's width but is also 100% of the parent width. If you do in fact want this element to be 8% to the left, the width would then need to be 92% in order to be contained within the parent.

Or just use padding:

```
// remove left: 8%
padding-left: 8%;
width: 92%
```

And you have this on `#footer_titles`:

```
left:3.5%;
```

So you need to explicitly set it's width to 96.5% or use the padding approach mentioned above.

And, for the sake of education, you're really asking for headaches using nested, relatively positioned elements. You should float elements and use margins or padding to offset elements. Or just use the flexible box model and be rid of relative and/or clear float headaches all together.

Comment: Even after this, there's a gap for some reason [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a1e03cxd/2/)

Comment: Updated answer. Just use padding.

Comment: I believe `footer_titles` is to be set to 0 as well.

Comment: @JBird I appreciate the issues which you have pointed out. The footer is now aligned perfectly with the rest of the page. But still the horizontal scroll bar appears.

Comment: @user3402248 have you added an overflow property to any container elements?

Comment: @user3402248 Take a look at the fiddle at the top of my answer. I'm not seeing a scroll bar.

Comment: @Jbird I forgot to add the width: 96.5%. It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Give `#footer_titles` to `left:0` and  `.footer_lowerspace` to `left:0` will solve your issue.

Because both have greater value and it will go out of box.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1e03cxd/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

in your ccs file for the class footer_lowerspace you have the following :

```
.footer_lowerspace{
    background-color:#707070;
    position: relative;
    top:20%;
    left:8%;
    width:100%;
}
```

giving this div a width of 100% and left 8% causes it to extend beyond  the viewport you should either remove left 8% or decrease the width to 92%. This should remove the horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

There's generally quite a few things in your CSS that wouldn't be advised. Basically, here's my more general advice:

- Avoid using position of relative or absolute and providing values for top and left
- It's much better to use margins and padding rather than top and left.
- A lot of elements (those with display values of block) fill up the available width on the screen by default, and setting them to have a width of 100% explicitly can have some other effects that it's best to avoid.
- Learn the difference between display values of block, inline and inline-block

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to point out for you.  Try putting in margin 0px and auto and padding 0px for your body.  In addition for a specific fix to your question when every you have an unwanted scroll bar you can but overflow hidden. Plus, your .footer_lowerspace you have a left 8% and a width of 100% which will cause that element to go out of view port.  In the CSS below I adjusted that and added body styles.

CSS

```
body {
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
      /*Main Header Container */
 .header{
    color:#FFFFFF;    /*White Color*/
    height:60px;
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
 }
/*Inner Logo Container on the left*/


 .header_logo{
     width:40%;
     height:100%;
     float:left;
 }
  #logo{
      height:100%;
      top:0;
      left:0;
       width:50%;
  }
 /*Inner Title Container on the right*/
 .header_title{
     width:60%;
     float:left;
  }
#titles{
   position:absolute;
   top:20px;
   font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif,Georgia;
   font-size:97%;
   color:#B8B8B8;
 }
 ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}
 li{
  display:inline-block;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:inherit;
 padding: 21px 10px;
}

ul a:hover{
  background-color:#666699;  /*Purple Color */

}

ul li ul{
  display:none; /*Hiding The Child Elements*/
 }
li ul li{
    padding: 21px 10px;
    background-color:#666699 ;
    }


 ul li:hover ul{   /*For all the ul elements whose parent is being hovered  over*/        
   display: block;
   position: absolute;

   width: 100%;
   top: 40px;
   left: 0;
   white-space: nowrap;
 }

 ul li ul li:hover{
    background-color:#C0C0C0;   
    }

  *{border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
 /*Main Content Section*/
 .content{
     height:525px;
     margin:auto;
     background-color:#C0C0C0;
    }
    img{
        width:100%;
        height:515px;
        }

     .footer {
    margin: auto;
    background-color:#707070;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer_upperspace  {
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
   height:40%;
   width: 100%;
}

.footer a:hover {
    background: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

 #footer_titles{
    position:relative;
    color:white;
    left:3.5%;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif,Georgia;
    font-size:80%;
  }

 .footer_lowerspace{
    background-color:#707070;
    position: relative;
    top:20%;

    width:100%;
    background-color: blue;
 }

#icon{
   width: 100%;
   height:2%;
   }
```